# MQCONN ended with reason code 2035

Tags: ibm-mq, solaris-10

I have recently installed Websphere MQ 7.5 on solaris machines. I was trying to test communication between workstations from [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp). When i ran

> ./amqsputc QUEUE1 saturn.queue.manager

It's giving output as

> Sample AMQSPUT0 start
>
> MQCONN ended with reason code 2035

I tried changing authorization for mqm user.

> setmqaut -m saturn.queue.manager -n queue1 -t queue -p mqm +all

and refreshed cache for saturn.queue.manager, still getting same error when trying to run "amqsputc ". What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I might be better consulting to the [v7.5 documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp) rather than v6.

Which host are you on when you are running this test? Which user is running the amqsputc command?

Your environment might not be set up. [Try this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016920_.htm):

```
export MQSERVER="Channel_Name/TCP/IP_or_Hostname(port_number)"
```